# Maintain speed in box2D body

Tags: box2d, libgdx

I want to delimit my speed and to maintain that speed constantly, but it gets getting higher and if i apply the linear velocity it doesnt bounce :/, Here is te part of my code

```
double fx = .25f*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation));
double fy = .25f*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotation));
this.getBody().applyLinearImpulse(World.toGameCoordinates((float)fx, (float)fy), this.bodydef.position);
this.getBody().setLinearVelocity(World.toGameCoordinates((float)fx, (float)fy));
```

What can i do to maintain the speed constant and it keeps bouncing

Comment: I'm confused at to what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to set a max velocity for a body?

Comment: It was my error, i was calling the method in the render, and thats why the speed was increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your code above is in an update loop (or in a callback)

In a physics engine you should never use anything similar to `set`. This is because the solver can no longer give you proper collisions (especially for a Continuous collision solver like Box2D). So your line:

```
this.getBody().setLinearVelocity(World.toGameCoordinates((float)fx, (float)fy));
```

Should not be there. That sets the velocity immediately and the ship will essentially *teleport* to the new position. As far as maintaining the current velocity goes, if you don't have any drag and you are not losing any energy in collisions, then you should never lose your initial velocity.

Comment: Yes it was in a loop, i remove it from there and problem resolved, thanks.